# Set default cache header for Azure storage container

Tags: azure, caching, azure-blob-storage, cache-control

I want to set a default cache header on all existing *and* future blobs in an Azure storage container.

I can only find tutorials on how to set cache headers for existing blobs: https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content/

How can I make sure future blobs also get that same header without having to run a script once every while? Maybe there is a way to set a default cache header on the container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today, it is not possible to specify either the default value for cache-control header on a blob or setting a value at container level that is applied to all blobs in that container. You would need to manually set the cache control header on the blobs either at the time of upload (for new blobs) or on existing blobs.

Comment: It's not written anywhere. Essentially there's no property on a blob container for default cache-control value. Also a blob has a property called cache-control that you can set.